# Sum formula for column in google spreadsheets

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

Let's say we have column A

[image: Pic1]

The sum formula start from the 2nd row. The sum is 5

When I'm adding new row above the 2nd row the sum formula includes the value from the first row.  The sum is 6

[image: Pic2]

I need the formula that will autoincrement the value of the starting row in the formula from 2 to 3 if the row is added above it:

```
=SUM(INDIRECT(ADDRESS(3,COLUMN(),4)&":"&ADDRESS(ROW()-1,COLUMN(),4)))
```

instead of

```
=SUM(INDIRECT(ADDRESS(2,COLUMN(),4)&":"&ADDRESS(ROW()-1,COLUMN(),4)))
```

The sum should be 5 if the new row is added above row 2

Also it should be adapted to this case:
[image: Pic3] 
When the value to sum is single there should be autoupdate of the formula to `=Sum(A1:A2)`
what I'm seeing when adding new row is: 
[image: Pic4]
The expected result is 3

Answer (score 1):

You can simply use the `SUM` function.

```cpp
=SUM(A2:A4)
```

[image]

You can use the following formula to return all the values from A1 up to the current row - 1:

```cpp
INDIRECT("A1:"&ROW()-1)
```

Then you can sum them:

```cpp
=SUM(INDIRECT("A1:"&ROW()-1))
```

[image]

And here's a more generic formula that returns the values in the current column from row 1 up to the current row - 1:

```cpp
=INDIRECT("R1C"&COLUMN()&":R"&ROW()-1&"C"&COLUMN(),0)
```

Comment: The solution will work if there are more than one row to sum. Updated the question with use case

Comment: Try to combine first and second answer, if we add new row at 1st position A1 will remain in the formula

Comment: I can't think of a way to do this since the INDIRECT approach doesn't have any information on what the previous range was. Are you sure you are not describing a [XY problem](https://xyproblem.info/)?